# Globals undefined in imported sources, but working in required sources

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Thanks for your consideration in this matter! I've spent the last few days scouring SO, GH, and everywhere else I could think of for any leads on this issue. Hoping that it is, in fact, an issue.

Given my webpack entry source:

```
global.val = 'some-value';

// 1) Global variables work just fine when the source is require'd
require('./second');

// 2) Global variables don't seem to be available when the source is imported
//   Results in: ReferenceError: val is not defined
import './second';
```

And my second source file is simply logging that value:

```
console.log(val);
```

If `second.js` is imported, `val` is undefined. If it's required, `val` is set to 'some-value' as it should be. I've not been able to find any explanation for this behaviour.

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',

      query: {
        presets: ['es2015','react']
      }
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Versions:

- Webpack: 1.12.9
- Babel: 6.0.0

I run the exact same code through Babel server-side without issue, but when I run it through Webpack and server it client-side, I end up with this issue. I've been kicking myself over this one for several days now. Would be grateful for any assistance you can offer! Let me know if you need any more info!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior and I'd expect Babel to do the same thing. `import` statements are processed before the body of the module is executed, so

```
global.val = 'some-value';
import './second';
```

will behave just like

```
import './second';
global.val = 'some-value';
```

If you really wanted to do this, you'd need to move the global assignment into its own module, e.g.

```
import './initialize-globals';
import './second';
```

Comment: After you answered, I googled for further information and came across your very similar answer here: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7069. My follow up question is this: why is this expected? Why does it make sense to evaluate imports before the rest of the body?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response by the way :)

Comment: I don't have a perfect answer here, it's the way the spec defines it, the same way functions declarations are available technically before that part of a file has been executed, imports are all processed up front. One reason that comes to mind is that if they weren't, it's not clear what something like `console.log(foo); import foo from 'bar';` would do, since the module wouldn't have even executed yet, `foo` wouldn't be `undefined` and it also wouldn't be `uninitialized`, it would be 100% unknown.

Comment: Roger. Seems sensible. I just figured that the import syntax was basically just sugar for the require syntax, hence my confusion. Thanks for your help!